# Using two networks for different websites

Tags: windows, networking, dns, routing, gateway

I have two internet connections one via WiFi and the other via Ethernet, i want to use one only to access Facebook and the other internet for the remaining websites.

```
I thought maybe if  i only allow Facebook domains on the first modem 
"allowed URLS" and some how configure the second modem as a fail over i 
can achieve my goal.
```

Windows.

Comment: http://www.ohmancorp.com/refwin-advfirewall.asp

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/229545/how-to-configure-different-firewall-rules-on-2-different-network-cards-in-window

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c3753e2d-0676-4b35-bd47-0d1e19ff7ed7/firewall-profiles-multiple-nics?forum=winserversecurity

Comment: The above links should work for you - using different connection types should allow you to implement two different firewall profiles.

Comment: Michael Nancarrow , Thank you very much , but will it use the right profile automatically  when i access the different sites , for example the private profile when i access facebook , and the public profile when i access the other sites ? what about the other protocols ?

Comment: The links purely outlined how to stop one mic accessing data, not dictating the route. Perhaps a static route could work.

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow I suggest you post an "Answer". The OP cannot accept comments as answers and other people searching will not see that there is an answer submitted to this question. It will appear in the index as "0" answers. Take the time to put together a well explained answer can gain you a lot of reputation.

Comment: Thank you again Michael , what about the host file can i dictate the routes using it so the links related to facebook can use a NIC1 and the * can use the NIC2 ?

Comment: @CharlieRB I would not consider my posts a valid answer, more resources for the OP to view.